Prove that a point must be inside circumcircle
Consider circumcircle $S$ of $\triangle abc$ and a point $v$ such that (i) $|\bar{va}| < |\bar{ab}|,|\bar{ac}|$ and (ii) $|\bar{vb}| < |\bar{ab}|,|\bar{bc}|$ and (iii)
$|\bar{vc}| < |\bar{ac}|,|\bar{bc}|$.  Prove that $v$ must be in the circumcircle $S$.
This's related to Delaunay triangulation and relative neighborhood graph.


Attempt.
Intuitively $\angle avb > \angle acb$ becuase $\bar{ab}$ is common to $\triangle avb$ and $\triangle acb$ and the other 2 sides of $\triangle avb$ are shorter that those of
$\triangle acb$. If indeed $\angle avb > \angle acb$ and both are subtended by same arc, then $v$ must be inside $S$ by the following fact

If they are not subtended by same arc, then applying above procedure again on
$\angle avc$ should work.
But I cannot prove  $\angle avb > \angle acb$ just by inspecting cosine formula.

Does your question notation indicate 1) VA<AB and VA<AC, or 2) VA<(AB+AC)? I assumed the latter on reading the question, but your diagram with dual < signs written by each segment seems to indicate the former.

@RobinSparrow (1), an equivalent way to write the inequalities is [($VA<AB$ and $VB<AB$) and ($VA<AC$ and $VC<AC$) and ($VC<BC$ and $VB<BC$)]. Here ($VA<AB$ and $VB<AB$) means $V$ is closer to $A$ and $B$ than they're to each other, therefore $AB$ will not be an edge in the Relative neighborhood graph

If, at each vertex, the distance to $V$ is less than the least side on the vertex, then the possible positions of $V$ are within the overlaps of $3$ circles, one centered on each vertex, each with radius of the smallest side on the vertex.
Let $BC$ be the shortest side (if there is one). On $B$ and $C$ we find two circles with radius $BC$ whose overlap is always a symmetric lens shape, which has portions within and without the circumcircle. Then either 1) the triangle is equilateral or isosceles with two long sides so that $AB=AC$, 2) the triangle is scalene with, say, $AB$ minimum, or 3) the triangle is isosceles with two short sides, say, $AB=BC$. The first and third cases are limiting cases, and all are illustrated in the diagram.

Because the third circle cannot be collinear with the others, or have radius longer than $AB$, it cannot add to the lens on $AB$ past $AB$, so our only concern is with the small segment on $BC$ and whether it lies within the circumcircle.
For all cases, $AB$ itself is on the circumcircle, and since $AO+OB>AB$, if we draw the diameter through $AO$, the circle on $AB$ cannot reach the circumcircle, implying the circle on $AB$ is within the circumcircle between the diameter and $B$. We therefore have $V$ within the circumcircle at all times, since the only time it is on the circle is at point $B$ (and point $C$ in case 1) but the circles are actually open, since $V$ must be less than the side distances away. So $V$ is within the circumcircle.

Thanks, I tried to more formally express your idea for the scalene triangle case below feel free to check

For any 2 circles, they intersect in at most 2 points. If we view circles CCW, then below we say $C_2$ enters $C_1$ at $q$ and leaves $C_1$ at $p$.

Suppose $BC < AB < CA$. For point $V$ to lie outside of the circumcircle $S$ of $\triangle ABC$ with center $O$, $OV$ must intersect one of the arcs ie. $Arc(AB),Arc(BC),Arc(CA)$.

We'll first show that $OV$ cannot intersect $Arc(BC)$. Notice $V$ must be inside the circle $Q$ entered at $A$ with radius $AB$ because it's given $VA<AB$.
Suppose $OV$ intersects $Arc(CB)$, then obviously $V$ is above $Arc(CB)$.

There's only one way $Q$ could intersect $S$ [1], that's $Q$ enters $S$ at $B$ and leaves $S$ at some point $K$ on $Arc(CA)$. But this means $Q$ is fully under $Arc(CB)$ and cannot possibly contain $V$, a contradiction.
Similarly, for $Arc(AB)$ we can consider the circle centered at $C$ with radius $BC$. For $Arc(CA)$ we consider the circle centered at $B$ with radius $BC$.

[1] We can show this by case analysis.

(i) $Q$ leaves $S$ at $B$, enters $S$ at $K$ on $Arc(CA)$ or $Arc(AB)$. This's impossible because it's given $AB < CA$.

(ii) $Q$ leaves $S$ at $B$, enters $S$ at $K$ on $Arc(CB)$. This's impossible since here $Q$ is not a circle centered at $A$.

(iii) $Q$ enters $S$ at $B$, leaves $S$ at $K$ on $Arc(CB)$. This's impossible because it's given $AB < CA$.

(iv) $Q$ enters $S$ at $B$, leaves $S$ at $K$ on $Arc(AB)$. This's impossible since here $Q$ is not a circle centered at $A$.

reference
J. W. Jaromczyk and M. Kowaluk. 1987. A note on relative neighborhood graphs.
